# Read xlsx file from local

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel, xlsx

I am having `xlsx` file under the path `src/excel/data.xlsx` .

So I am trying to get the data from this excel and form array.

**Code tried:**

```
import * as XLSX from "xlsx";

export function App() {
  fetch("./excel/data.xlsx")
    .then((res) => res.arrayBuffer())
    .then((ab) => {
      const wb = XLSX.read(ab, { type: "array" });
      console.log("html ", wb);
    });

  return <div>Hello World</div>;
}
```

**Error:**

> Invalid HTML: could not find < table >

If I give *correct path `./excel/data.xlsx` or wrong path `notvalid.xlsx`* in this line `fetch("./excel/data.xlsx")` , then I get the same error like above, so I think it may be error due to path setting but I am not sure.

**Requirement:**

I am in the need to read the data from `excel/data.xlsx` file and get the data as array.

**Working Example:**

[image: Edit old-lake-d2ygth]

Please help me to achieve the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an issue with the path you are passing to fetch. If you want to use fetch, then put the excel file in your public folder. If it is a project generated with `create-react-app`. Place your excel file in `public/excel/data.xlsx` and change the path you are passing to fetch ie `fetch('excel/data.xlsx')`. If you are using any other bundler or framework to generate your project, just make sure that the excel file is in the folder that is served by your application if you want to use `fetch` with it.

Here is it working on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-surf-ezvrxh)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution here for `React.js`. The excel sheet should be under the `public` folder.

```
import * as XLSX from "xlsx";

export function App() {
  function Upload() {
    var url = "excel/data.xlsx";
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("GET", url, true);
    oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

    oReq.onload = function (e) {
      var arraybuffer = oReq.response;

      /* convert data to binary string */
      var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
      var arr = new Array();
      for (var i = 0; i !== data.length; ++i)
        arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
      var bstr = arr.join("");

      /* Call XLSX */
      var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {
        type: "binary"
      });

      /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */
      var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
      /* Get worksheet */
      var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
      console.log(
        XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {
          raw: true
        })
      );
    };

    oReq.send();
    console.log("Read!@");
  }
  return <button onClick={Upload}>Click me</button>;
}
```

This approach works on the server side:

```
import * as XLSX from "xlsx";

export function App() {
  let workbook = XLSX.readFile('./src/excel/data.xlsx');
  let sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
  let xlData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]]);
  console.log(xlData);

  return <div>Hello World</div>;
}
```

If you are trying on the client side, you'll need to upload the excel file by input and then process it accordingly.

```js
function Upload() {
const fileUpload = (document.getElementById('fileUpload'));
const regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.xls|.xlsx)$/;
if (regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
    let fileName = fileUpload.files[0].name;
    if (typeof (FileReader) !== 'undefined') {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        if (reader.readAsBinaryString) {
            reader.onload = (e) => {
                processExcel(reader.result);
            };
            reader.readAsBinaryString(fileUpload.files[0]);
        }
    } else {
        console.log("This browser does not support HTML5.");
    }
} else {
    console.log("Please upload a valid Excel file.");
}
}

function processExcel(data) {
    const workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'binary'});
    const firstSheet = workbook.SheetNames[0];
    const excelRows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[firstSheet]);

    console.log(excelRows);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Process Excel File</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.16.0/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input class="upload-excel" type="file" id="fileUpload" onchange="Upload()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, could you be able to fork my above given example and make the changes and share it back?

Comment: I get the new error as `Cannot access file ./src/excel/data.xlsx` . Forked with your solution here https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-goldstine-uztbke

Comment: `https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/solutions/input/` You can read more about how to use it here @HelloWorld

Comment: readFile is only available in server environments. Browsers have no API for reading arbitrary files given a path, so another strategy must be used. @HelloWorld

Comment: Yes how can I implement that another strategy in reactjs way to make it successful?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46909260/reading-excel-file-in-reactjs 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61795452/reading-excel-file-in-react
@HelloWorld

Comment: I have updated the answer. Hope it helps! @HelloWorld

Comment: Still getting error after tying like the updated solution. Again refer link here https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-goldstine-uztbke . Here I am not uploading the file manually instead trying to read it from local. Please feel free to make the changes in the codesandbox I have provided.

Comment: Bro, I am telling that I will not manually upload the file using input. It will be read directly from the local folder. You have provided updated solution where user needs to click the choose file input and manuaaly upload an excel and see the data. This is not what I am in the need.

Comment: The data needs to be read from local `data.xlsx` file.

Comment: @HelloWorld Please check the updated answer again

Comment: It turns out that your original solution was not working because the file should be under `public` directory @HelloWorld

Answer (score 1):

After reading this SheetJS issue on GitHub ([Invalid HTML: could not find  #1110](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/1110)), I get the idea that it could be an issue with your `fetch`-request receiving a HTML-page rather than an XLSM-file. Perhaps you're simply referencing the file with the wrong URL which is giving a 404 response, which is a HTML file, which starts with '<', which is interpreted as HTML, which will give an error not knowing what `<table>` is.

All of this is speculations derived from the answers in the GitHub issue.

Make sure that you can download your XLSM-file by going to `yourwebsiteurl.com/path/to/app/folder/excel/data.xlsm`. You could also provide us with the file structure on your web server regarding your `index.html` file and your `data.xlsm` file so that we can make sure that the URL is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that your original solution was not working because the file should be under the `public` directory. Placing the files under the `public` directory, the code works correctly!